# how to always return rows in the same order

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (call it "DimMonth") that I often want to select a subset of successive rows from by some numeric column (say "Month").  I always specify the min / max row in this subset, as well as the number of rows in the subset.  DimMonth.Month is an integer that represents year and month (in format YYYYMM), with values like 202001, 202012, 202103, etc.  There are no keys or indexes defined for the table (although, Month is a foreign key to other tables).  What is the best way to go about selecting this subset of rows?

For example, say @month = 202103, and that I want to select it and the 3 months before it.  So, I expect a result like:

```
202103
202102
202101
202012
```

As far as I know, due to order of execution, even though the following solution works sometimes, I can't rely upon it to work all the time:

```
SELECT TOP 4
    Month
FROM
    dbo.DimMonth
WHERE
    Month <= @month
ORDER BY
    Month DESC
```

....since SELECT is executed before ORDER BY.

A solution which I know works but is tedious to write every time (and is costly for the CTE, since the result set will grow over time) is:

```
WITH
all_months_before_desired_month AS
(
    SELECT
        Month
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            ORDER BY
                Month DESC
        ) AS RowNum
    FROM
        dbo.DimMonth
    WHERE
        Month <= @month
)
,SELECT
    Month
FROM
    all_months_before_desired_month 
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN 1 AND 4
;
```

I think the right answer here is to define a key or an index (so that I can use my first solution, but without the ORDER BY), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY is always executed first, and then SELECT.
It does not matter that ORDER BY is at the end.

If you have no ORDER BY, then the results are in unpredictable order, that is also subject to change.

Comment: Everything I have read says that SELECT gets executed before ORDER BY.  But, that's not what I'm primarily concerned about.  What I'm asking is...  What's the best way to return a subset of successive (ordered) rows from a table, wherein I parameterize the min / max row of the subset and the number of rows in the subset?  Doing this with a nested query with ROW_NUMBER() will be costly (because the subquery result set will grow in size) and tedious to develop (2 queries to write, instead of 1).

Comment: The order by will be executed first because of the TOP operator. The way you have constructed the query is fine, it will always order correctly.

Comment: @skyline01, the logical order in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) shows `ORDER BY` is nearly last, only followed by `TOP`. The actual physical order could be first, depending on the execution plan. The plan will depend much on available indexes. Note the `ORDER BY` column(s) will need to uniquely identify a row for deterministic results.